# Handling of Position instances in java swing documents

Tags: java, swing, document

I try to customize the `PlainDocument` class in java swing.

My purpose is to mark the structures of the text (like headers, footnotes, and so on) with instances of the `Position` interface in the `javax.swing.text` package.

You can insert `Position` objects with the `createPosition(int offset)` method of the `AbstractDocument` class.

At this point the following problems occured for me:

1. How can I track the inserted `Position` objects back? (there are methods to get the start- and
   end `Position` of a document, but nothing more)
2. Related to this problem: How can i instantiate Position objects?

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I read over that the `createPosition` method has a return parameter of the type Position. Thats all of the problem. So question was not really necessary.

To complete this anyway: Just declare a Hashmap `HashMap<Integer, Position>` on a customized `Document` and safe in it all created Positions releated to the order of their creation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Document is in fact a tree of Elements which has start/end offsets (in fact the positions). So use documentInstance.getDefaultRootElement() and get the Element's children
2. AbstractDocument has method to create Positions

   ```
   public synchronized Position createPosition(int offs) throws BadLocationException
   ```

Comment: The problem with this proposal is, that the underlying tree of a 'PlainDocument' at least is also structured by line breaks. That means every line break of the text creates a separate 'LeafElement'. For my task it would be necessary to exclusively reccur to Position objects.

Comment: I don't see any problem with leaf elements. Anyway you can create your own Position instances and keep them in your classes and of course use them.